# Mysql2 gem installed but can't be required

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, rvm

I'm converting a Rails-2.3 project over to 3.0.3, and I'm running into a vexing issue with the mysql2 gem. It's listed in my Gemfile, I ran bundle install successfully. When I list my local gems, mysql2 is there.

But when I try to open a rails console I get [this stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/706057) that tells me mysql2 isn't installed.

I'm using RVM for gem management as you can tell from the stacktrace, but everything else in the environment seems to be working okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to change the adapter in `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: Had the same problem and this was my fix too.